# Does i in for loops means iteration or index?

Tags: history, loops

Does i in for loops means iteration or index?

How could I know the original meaning? Some programmers say it's iteration, some say it's index.

It seems to me more of an index we start from --- we go from zero, to the first in length (which is one, of course), and so forth.

But this still doesn't "prove" to me which from both terms is correct, if at all.

Comment: See [Loop Counter under For-Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Loop_counters), as affirmation of @RobertHarvey's answer; see also [Loop Control Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_variable_(programming))

Comment: Wow. And I thought that it was for integer.

Comment: Depending on the loop it can be iteration, index, both or neither.

Comment: If I'm counting number of connection attempts, I start with 1.  If I'm looping an array, I start with 0.  The loop variable has different meanings according to its context.  It would be incorrect to call it an index I'd think.

Comment: Usually double- and triple-nested `for` loops use `j` and `k` respectively, so to me, they have always looked from the beginning like the `i, j, k` components of things like a vector in physics and math.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't mean either.

It is a **variable** containing a number that can be used as an index value for an array item. This is evidenced by the fact that `i` is often used in the context of an array, as in

```
array[i]
```

The index value represents the number of the currently executing **iteration.**  More specifically, the body of the loop (the instructions that are executed during each loop repetition) can be said to be *iterated* as the loop executes.  If the item's index value is six, and an array is being iterated, then it's the *seventh iteration* (since array indices typically start counting at zero).

That said, there's no requirement that `i` be used as an index in an array; it might be used in some other context. The notion of loop variables named `i`, `j`, `k`, etc. originates in mathematics, where it is an established convention for writing subscripts.  It was carried over from mathematics to programming in Fortran, where variables named `i` through `n` default to the `integer` data type.

Comment: And it comes from common mathematics notation, specifically, subscripts.

Comment: So it is a variable containing the index of the current item (value) in a collection (say, array), and this current item reflects the current iteration.

Comment: Not quite.  It is a variable containing a number that *can be used as an index in an array.*  If its value is six, and an array is being iterated, then it's the seventh iteration (since array indices typically start counting at zero).  But there's no requirement that `i` be used as an index in an array; it might be used in some other context.

Comment: Since j and k don't stand for "index" or whatever, IMO, the truly correct answer is that i stands for i.  :-)

Comment: Robert, in this saying `It was carried over from mathematics to programming in the Fortran language, where variables named `i` through `n` default to the `integer` data type.`, did you mean that in a certain time, `i` replaced `n` in Fortran?

Comment: No, I don't mean that.  I mean that `i`, `j`,`k`,`l`,`m`, and `n` all default to `integer` in Fortran.

Comment: After 25+ years of programming C and then C++ in the predominantly Electrical Engineering and mathematical/statistical domains.. I have abandoned the notation of i, j, k, as "index" or iterator counter notation... Since in C/C++ indexing starts at ZERO (as it should be) and ID's in database's almost always start at ONE.. i always use ix, jx, kx, etc for "indeXes" that start counting at zero.. and id, jd, kd or "row_ix" or "row_id" for looping variables..because in math, i, j, and k always refer to Current, Imaginary numbers, or some other Vector component of some math construct.